# Jinja2 template if/else statement

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-template

In a jinja2 template file, I'm attempting to find a string in a server hostname, then apply the settings I want based on what it found. Here is what I have. This works, however, everything is getting the developmenthosts setting.

`{% if 'dev' or 'tst' or 'test' or 'eng' in ansible_hostname %} {{ developmenthosts }} {% else %} {{ productionhosts }} {% endif %}`

Any help would be great, and I'm fairly new using jinja2 templates.

Comment: and what is the value of `ansible_hostname` ?

Comment: ansible_hostname would be one of four, for my testing it would be 
lnx-dev-01, lnx-tst-01, lnx-stg-01, lnx-prd-01

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following, using `regex_search` the if/else can be written in shorter and cleaner format.

```
"{{ developmenthosts if ( ansible_hostname|regex_search('dev|tst|test|eng') ) else  productionhosts }}"
```

Example:

```
---

- name: Sample playbook
  connection: local
  #  gather_facts: false
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
   developmenthosts: MYDEVHOST
   productionhosts: MYPRODHOST
  tasks:
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ ansible_hostname }}"
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ developmenthosts if ( ansible_hostname |regex_search('dev|tst|test|eng') ) else  productionhosts }}"
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked flawlessly.